# Stripe payment intents examples for server side submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am looking at Stripe payment gateway with Payment intent API. All examples on the official page consist of example with jquery submit with function - payWithCard (function name).

Do we have any example where we could submit on server and do some validation before sending for payment?

With Charge API, we could post data on server and then we could send for payment.

Is it possible with Payment Intent API or I need to go with Jquery ?

Comment: Are you referring to confirming the Payment Intent later? https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm

Comment: @Alex, i was trying something like "Charge" api. Once we click submit button then entire process is send to server side but with payment Intent API , on click of submit button entire execution happens in client side.

Comment: If you include `confirm=true`, then you don't have to do a separate confirmation : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm

Answer (score 1):

You can go through Stripe documentation for details. When implementing Stripe we actually use both Server Side and Javascript. I am providing here sample working code.

Download Stripe package, I am using PHP here from the [Github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) repository.

Then in the html page use the below javascript

```
    function handleStripe() {               

        var stripe = Stripe("STRIPE PUBLISHABLE KEY");

        var data = {
            "sess": "Some valuable data",
            "rcom": "Some valuable data"
        };
    
        fetch("stripe-intent-book.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            var elements = stripe.elements({
                fonts: [
                    {
                        cssSrc: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand',
                    },
                ],
                locale: window.__exampleLocale,
            });         

            var elementStyles = {
                base: {
                    color: '#32325D',
                    fontWeight: 500,
                    fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro, Consolas, Menlo, monospace',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',

                    '::placeholder': {
                        color: '#CFD7DF',
                    },
                    ':-webkit-autofill': {
                        color: '#e39f48',
                    },
                },
                invalid: {
                    color: '#E25950',

                    '::placeholder': {
                        color: '#FFCCA5',
                    },
                },
            };

            var elementClasses = {
                focus: 'focused',
                empty: 'empty',
                invalid: 'invalid',
            };
        
            var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
                style: elementStyles,
                classes: elementClasses,
            });
            cardNumber.mount('#card-number');

            var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
                style: elementStyles,
                classes: elementClasses,
            });
            cardExpiry.mount('#card-expiry');

            var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
                style: elementStyles,
                classes: elementClasses,
            });
            cardCvc.mount('#card-cvc');
        
            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.stripeCC .input');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
                    input.classList.add('focused');
                });
                input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
                    input.classList.remove('focused');
                });
                input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                    if (input.value.length === 0) {
                        input.classList.add('empty');
                    } else {
                        input.classList.remove('empty');
                    }
                });
            });

            cardNumber.on("change", function (event) {
                document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
                document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
            });
        
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                payWithCard(stripe, cardNumber, data.clientSecret);
            });

        });
    
    }
```

And the server side PHP code below

```
    <?php   

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("Stripe Secret key");

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        try {

            $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
            $sess           = $json_obj->sess;
            $rcom           = $json_obj->rcom;
    
            $amt            = 10; /* Specify the amount to be charged here */
            $amt            = $amt * 100;

            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => $amt,
                'currency' => 'gbp'
            ]);

            $output = [
                'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
            ];

            echo json_encode($output);
        } catch (Error $e) {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }

    ?>
```

From the Stripe API reference below is the .Net code, requesting you to go through the [Stripe API doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=dotnet) please

```
    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_tR3PYbcVNZZ796tH88S4VQ2u";

    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
    {
        Amount = 1099,
        Currency = "usd",
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
            "card",
        },
    };

    var service = new PaymentIntentService();
    var intent = service.Create(options);
```

Comment: payWithCard function is jquery function If i am right and i am looking in MVC c# for server side.

Comment: @Hector edited my answer to include .Net code.

Comment: @Subhasis I have seen this code but i wanted post custom model on server which i will capture in payment page on the server then send payment confirmation from server but as i see we need to handle everything in jquery with new API.